# Looking for a paper in the game theory literature

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I am looking for a paper I've read several years ago, but I cannot find it using google. I think it is quite well known.

It is about prices and their indication about quality. There are informed and uninformed buyers, as the informed buyers know the value of goods, prices tend to reflect the value/quality. Uninformed buyers can take advantage of this by using the price as a signal of quality.

Does anybody know the author/title and year of this paper?

Comment: Possibly : (August 2010) https://www.cerge-ei.cz/pdf/wp/Wp413.pdf ?

Comment: It was not that paper, but the topic is very identical. I will check their references, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLIGOPOLISTIC PRICE COMPETITION
WITH INFORMED AND UNINFORMED
BUYERS

by

Michal Ostatnický

https://www.cerge-ei.cz/pdf/wp/Wp413.pdf

Any good ?

Reputation: The New Palgrave Dictionary
Martin Cripps, March 2006
https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/14446/1/14446.pdf

I Googled using >>"uninformed buyer" game theory<<

Looks like an interesting topic

Comment: Thank you, this really helps!